# How to make webpack not bundle json when using require syntax?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I'm importing a json file using 
`const settings = require("settings.json");`

How do I tell webpack that I do not want it bundled, that I want to load it at runtime instead?

Comment: According to [`webpack`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) documentation you should be good to omit _.json_ extension in your `require`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I only needed to add a externals option to webpack.config.js:

`externals: {
    "../settings.json": "commonjs ../settings.json",
},`

I still haven't found any doc about it though.

Comment: Documented here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals

Answer (score 0):

Use a [XHR request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)) to load it instead of requiring it.

The required files will be bundled with all other files but the fetch lets you "require" them at will and asyncronously.

Comment: I knew i could do this, but i really wanted to load the json with require